# PostgreSQL и MongoDB при запросе WHERE IN

Tags: postgresql, mongodb

У меня есть таблица Postgres:

```
CREATE TABLE report
(
    id     serial primary key,
    sensor_id integer,
    datetime timestamp,
    ...(many other fields)
);
```

А также коллекция в MongoDB, там те же данные.
Созданы индексы в Postgres (создавал их как единовременно, так и по отдельности, разницы в результате не увидел)

```
create index report_datetime on report (datetime desc);
create index report_sensor_datetime on report (datetime desc, sensor_id);
create index report_sensor_datetime_1 on report (sensor_id, datetime desc);
```

Единственный инденкс в Монге:

```
...createIndex({"sensor_id" : 1, "datetime" : -1})
```

Таблица\коллекция содержит больше 100 миллионов записей.

**Мой вопрос такой:** почему такой запрос в postgres:

```
select *
from report
where sensor_id in (10234, 10236, 10250, 10251, 10253, 10255, 10262, 10263, 10264, 10265, 10267)
order by datetime desc
limit 100;
```

выполняется несколько десятков секунд (подробности ниже в explain), а подобный в Mongo:

```
db.getCollection('report').find({sensor_id: {$in: [
    ObjectId("5f1833aa44be73ead6de88c9"),
    ObjectId("5f1833ad44be73ead6de8977"),
    ObjectId("5f18a0867c9195aa25ac0bb0"),
    ObjectId("5f18a0867c9195aa25ac0bb5"),
    ObjectId("5f18a0a47c9195aa25ac1241"),
    ObjectId("5f1927b87c9195aa25b5203c"),
    ObjectId("5f1a5f617c9195aa25e2d4df"),
    ObjectId("5f1a5f647c9195aa25e2db3b"),
    ObjectId("5f1a5f647c9195aa25e2db42"),
    ObjectId("5f1a5f647c9195aa25e2db59"),
    ObjectId("5f1a69027c9195aa25e4f84d")
]}}).sort({datetime:-1}).limit(100)
```

за несколько миллисекунд?

**Как мне оптимизировать запрос, индексы или структуру в Postgres для такого же результата?** Ну не верится, что для Postgres такой запрос настолько сложнее, чем для монги

Mongo explain:

```
    db.getCollection('report').find({sensor_id: {$in: [
        ObjectId("5f1833aa44be73ead6de88c9"),
        ObjectId("5f1833ad44be73ead6de8977"),
        ObjectId("5f18a0867c9195aa25ac0bb0"),
        ObjectId("5f18a0867c9195aa25ac0bb5"),
        ObjectId("5f18a0a47c9195aa25ac1241"),
        ObjectId("5f1927b87c9195aa25b5203c"),
        ObjectId("5f1a5f617c9195aa25e2d4df"),
        ObjectId("5f1a5f647c9195aa25e2db3b"),
        ObjectId("5f1a5f647c9195aa25e2db42"),
        ObjectId("5f1a5f647c9195aa25e2db59"),
        ObjectId("5f1a69027c9195aa25e4f84d")
    ]}}).sort({datetime:-1}).limit(100).explain()
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "patrol.report",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "sensor_id" : {
                "$in" : [ 
                    ObjectId("5f1833aa44be73ead6de88c9"), 
                    ObjectId("5f1833ad44be73ead6de8977"), 
                    ObjectId("5f18a0867c9195aa25ac0bb0"), 
                    ObjectId("5f18a0867c9195aa25ac0bb5"), 
                    ObjectId("5f18a0a47c9195aa25ac1241"), 
                    ObjectId("5f1927b87c9195aa25b5203c"), 
                    ObjectId("5f1a5f617c9195aa25e2d4df"), 
                    ObjectId("5f1a5f647c9195aa25e2db3b"), 
                    ObjectId("5f1a5f647c9195aa25e2db42"), 
                    ObjectId("5f1a5f647c9195aa25e2db59"), 
                    ObjectId("5f1a69027c9195aa25e4f84d")
                ]
            }
        },
        "queryHash" : "C4968B0D",
        "planCacheKey" : "58DC1ACB",
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "LIMIT",
            "limitAmount" : 100,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "SORT_MERGE",
                    "sortPattern" : {
                        "datetime" : -1.0
                    },
                    "inputStages" : [ 
                        {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "sensor_id" : 1,
                                "datetime" : -1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "sensor_datetime",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                "sensor_id" : [],
                                "datetime" : []
                            },
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 2,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "sensor_id" : [ 
                                    "[ObjectId('5f1833aa44be73ead6de88c9'), ObjectId('5f1833aa44be73ead6de88c9')]"
                                ],
                                "datetime" : [ 
                                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "sensor_id" : 1,
                                "datetime" : -1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "sensor_datetime",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                "sensor_id" : [],
                                "datetime" : []
                            },
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 2,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "sensor_id" : [ 
                                    "[ObjectId('5f1833ad44be73ead6de8977'), ObjectId('5f1833ad44be73ead6de8977')]"
                                ],
                                "datetime" : [ 
                                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "sensor_id" : 1,
                                "datetime" : -1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "sensor_datetime",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                "sensor_id" : [],
                                "datetime" : []
                            },
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 2,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "sensor_id" : [ 
                                    "[ObjectId('5f18a0867c9195aa25ac0bb0'), ObjectId('5f18a0867c9195aa25ac0bb0')]"
                                ],
                                "datetime" : [ 
                                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "sensor_id" : 1,
                                "datetime" : -1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "sensor_datetime",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                "sensor_id" : [],
                                "datetime" : []
                            },
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 2,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "sensor_id" : [ 
                                    "[ObjectId('5f18a0867c9195aa25ac0bb5'), ObjectId('5f18a0867c9195aa25ac0bb5')]"
                                ],
                                "datetime" : [ 
                                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "sensor_id" : 1,
                                "datetime" : -1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "sensor_datetime",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                "sensor_id" : [],
                                "datetime" : []
                            },
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 2,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "sensor_id" : [ 
                                    "[ObjectId('5f18a0a47c9195aa25ac1241'), ObjectId('5f18a0a47c9195aa25ac1241')]"
                                ],
                                "datetime" : [ 
                                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "sensor_id" : 1,
                                "datetime" : -1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "sensor_datetime",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                "sensor_id" : [],
                                "datetime" : []
                            },
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 2,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "sensor_id" : [ 
                                    "[ObjectId('5f1927b87c9195aa25b5203c'), ObjectId('5f1927b87c9195aa25b5203c')]"
                                ],
                                "datetime" : [ 
                                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "sensor_id" : 1,
                                "datetime" : -1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "sensor_datetime",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                "sensor_id" : [],
                                "datetime" : []
                            },
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 2,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "sensor_id" : [ 
                                    "[ObjectId('5f1a5f617c9195aa25e2d4df'), ObjectId('5f1a5f617c9195aa25e2d4df')]"
                                ],
                                "datetime" : [ 
                                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "sensor_id" : 1,
                                "datetime" : -1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "sensor_datetime",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                "sensor_id" : [],
                                "datetime" : []
                            },
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 2,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "sensor_id" : [ 
                                    "[ObjectId('5f1a5f647c9195aa25e2db3b'), ObjectId('5f1a5f647c9195aa25e2db3b')]"
                                ],
                                "datetime" : [ 
                                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "sensor_id" : 1,
                                "datetime" : -1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "sensor_datetime",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                "sensor_id" : [],
                                "datetime" : []
                            },
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 2,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "sensor_id" : [ 
                                    "[ObjectId('5f1a5f647c9195aa25e2db42'), ObjectId('5f1a5f647c9195aa25e2db42')]"
                                ],
                                "datetime" : [ 
                                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "sensor_id" : 1,
                                "datetime" : -1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "sensor_datetime",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                "sensor_id" : [],
                                "datetime" : []
                            },
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 2,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "sensor_id" : [ 
                                    "[ObjectId('5f1a5f647c9195aa25e2db59'), ObjectId('5f1a5f647c9195aa25e2db59')]"
                                ],
                                "datetime" : [ 
                                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "sensor_id" : 1,
                                "datetime" : -1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "sensor_datetime",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                "sensor_id" : [],
                                "datetime" : []
                            },
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 2,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "sensor_id" : [ 
                                    "[ObjectId('5f1a69027c9195aa25e4f84d'), ObjectId('5f1a69027c9195aa25e4f84d')]"
                                ],
                                "datetime" : [ 
                                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ 
            {
                "stage" : "SORT",
                "sortPattern" : {
                    "datetime" : -1.0
                },
                "limitAmount" : 100,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "sensor_id" : -1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "sensor_id",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                "sensor_id" : []
                            },
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 2,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "sensor_id" : [ 
                                    "[ObjectId('5f1a69027c9195aa25e4f84d'), ObjectId('5f1a69027c9195aa25e4f84d')]", 
                                    "[ObjectId('5f1a5f647c9195aa25e2db59'), ObjectId('5f1a5f647c9195aa25e2db59')]", 
                                    "[ObjectId('5f1a5f647c9195aa25e2db42'), ObjectId('5f1a5f647c9195aa25e2db42')]", 
                                    "[ObjectId('5f1a5f647c9195aa25e2db3b'), ObjectId('5f1a5f647c9195aa25e2db3b')]", 
                                    "[ObjectId('5f1a5f617c9195aa25e2d4df'), ObjectId('5f1a5f617c9195aa25e2d4df')]", 
                                    "[ObjectId('5f1927b87c9195aa25b5203c'), ObjectId('5f1927b87c9195aa25b5203c')]", 
                                    "[ObjectId('5f18a0a47c9195aa25ac1241'), ObjectId('5f18a0a47c9195aa25ac1241')]", 
                                    "[ObjectId('5f18a0867c9195aa25ac0bb5'), ObjectId('5f18a0867c9195aa25ac0bb5')]", 
                                    "[ObjectId('5f18a0867c9195aa25ac0bb0'), ObjectId('5f18a0867c9195aa25ac0bb0')]", 
                                    "[ObjectId('5f1833ad44be73ead6de8977'), ObjectId('5f1833ad44be73ead6de8977')]", 
                                    "[ObjectId('5f1833aa44be73ead6de88c9'), ObjectId('5f1833aa44be73ead6de88c9')]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "mongo",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "4.2.12",
        "gitVersion" : "5593fd8e33b60c75802edab304e23998fa0ce8a5"
    },
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```

Postgres explain:

```
explain (analyze, buffers)
select *
from report
where sensor_id in (10234, 10236, 10250, 10251, 10253, 10255, 10262, 10263, 10264, 10265, 10267)
order by datetime desc
limit 100;

Limit  (cost=0.57..3984.27 rows=100 width=312) (actual time=147481.199..154733.025 rows=100 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=16330933 read=631496
  ->  Index Scan using report_datetime on report  (cost=0.57..69625427.65 rows=1747758 width=312) (actual time=147481.195..154732.770 rows=100 loops=1)
        Filter: (sensor_id = ANY ('{10234,10236,10250,10251,10253,10255,10262,10263,10264,10265,10267}'::integer[]))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 17276154
        Buffers: shared hit=16330933 read=631496
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=128 read=3
Planning Time: 14.662 ms
Execution Time: 154733.156 ms
```

**Дополнение:** Когда я повторно запускаю запрос к Postgres с теми же параметрами, он выполняется быстрее (но все равно несоизмеримо с монгой), но любое добавление\измененией\удаление списка sensor_id опять все запускает по новой. Монга же выполняет "моментально" этот запрос вне зависимости от параметров. Explain Postgres'а повторного запроса:

```
explain (analyze, buffers)
select *
from report
where sensor_id in (10234, 10236, 10250, 10251, 10253, 10255, 10262, 10263, 10264, 10265, 10267)
order by datetime desc
limit 100;

Limit  (cost=0.57..3984.27 rows=100 width=312) (actual time=22828.487..22949.028 rows=100 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=16932070 read=30359
  ->  Index Scan using report_datetime on report  (cost=0.57..69625427.65 rows=1747758 width=312) (actual time=22828.483..22948.984 rows=100 loops=1)
        Filter: (sensor_id = ANY ('{10234,10236,10250,10251,10253,10255,10262,10263,10264,10265,10267}'::integer[]))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 17276154
        Buffers: shared hit=16932070 read=30359
Planning Time: 0.253 ms
Execution Time: 22949.084 ms
```

Конфиг Postgres (mongo рабоает в docker на дефолтных настройках:

```
max_connections = 200
shared_buffers = 8GB
effective_cache_size = 24GB
maintenance_work_mem = 2GB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.7
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 100
random_page_cost = 4
effective_io_concurrency = 2
work_mem = 10485kB
min_wal_size = 1GB
max_wal_size = 4GB
max_worker_processes = 8
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 4
max_parallel_workers = 8
max_parallel_maintenance_workers = 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
select * from unnest(array[10234, 10236, 10250, 10251, 10253, 10255, 10262, 10263, 10264, 10265, 10267]) as k
join lateral (select * from am where i = k order by v desc limit 100) as r on true
order by datetime desc limit 100
```

Судя по explain, mongodb делает именно так.

---

Техника родственная [`Loose indexscan`](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Loose_indexscan) (`index skip scan`), в такой задаче нередко оптимальнее произвести поиск по индексу заново с новым префиксом, чем пытаться выполнить просмотр за один раз. Но автоматически такое преобразование планировщик postgresql действительно делать пока не умеет. А потому планировщику остаётся или отправиться вычитать все строки по sensor_id и затем их сортировать, либо пойти по индексу по отсортированным datetime в расчёте быстро встретить заданные sensor_id. Вы наблюдаете второй сценарий. И как отчётливо видно по `Rows Removed by Filter` - наступает этот счастливый момент после пустого перебора большого объёма данных.